# Console doesn't log new variable in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

In a for loop, I am assigning a new variable to an array. When I use console.log to print the array, it doesn't log it. What may be the problem? Here is the code:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

function countPosts(categories, posts) {

    var categoriesLength = categories.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoriesLength; i++) {
        categories[i].post_count = _.filter(posts, function (post) {
            return post.category.name_slug == categories[i].name_slug;
        }).length;
        console.log(categories[i].post_count);
    }
    console.log(categories);
    return categories;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
3
2
2

[ { __v: 0,
    name: 'General',
    name_slug: 'general',
    _id: 5680feb3b8ba7c9c298e7666 },
  { __v: 0,
    name: 'New Cat',
    name_slug: 'new-cat',
    _id: 568109d190ca9da13629724a },
  { __v: 0,
    name: 'Private',
    name_slug: 'private',
    _id: 56810b13b8bdcfc138295e81 }]
```

Shouldn't there be a variable named `post_count` in logged array?

Comment: Could you set this up in jsbin or somewhere? From glancing at the code, I see no reason why the categories don't contain a `post_count` member.

Comment: To me the code looks just fine, but maybe try replacing the for loop with map and return the new array?

Comment: Console debugging can be confusing when you log mutable objects. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(categories))`?

Comment: @supafabulous the code also works just fine! I just wondered why console doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @ChrisMartin sadly, didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What does it do?

Comment: @JohannesJander I am new to JS therefore I don't actually know how to set it up in jsbin. Can you help a little bit?

Comment: What happens if you assign a simple value to the categories[i].post_count ? Wouldn't it still show in the log.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Sorry for not explaining clearly. It logs this: `[{"_id":"5680feb3b8ba7c9c298e7666","name_slug":"general","name":"General","__v":0},{"_id":"568109d190ca9da13629724a","name_slug":"new-cat","name":"New Cat","__v":0},{"_id":"56810b13b8bdcfc138295e81","name_slug":"private","name":"Private","__v":0}]`

Comment: Go to jsbin.com and paste your javascript code into the javascript tab. Also add some example for the posts array in a variable. It's really easy.

Comment: @JohannesJander It actually logged in JSBin. Here is the [link](http://jsbin.com/payasoqeho/1/edit?js,console). I am using WebStorm by the way.

Comment: Then you should go back to your code and see what you did differently (old version, looking at the wrong tab console...), on JSBin it is working fine as it should.